# M2: How to add a canonical tag on the login page

Tags: magento2, login, seo, canonical

These links are getting indexed:

https://store.com/customer/account/login/referer/aHR0cHM6Ly9zdG9yZS5zbWFydGRlc2tzLmNvbS90ZXJtcy1jb25kaXRpb25z/
https://store.com/customer/account/login/referer/aHR0cHM6Ly9zdG9yZS5zbWFydGRlc2tzLmNvbS93b3JrLWZyb20taG9tZS5odG1s/
https://store.com/customer/account/login/referer/aHR0cHM6Ly9zdG9yZS5zbWFydGRlc2tzLmNvbS9jYXRhbG9nL2NhdGVnb3J5L3ZpZXcvaWQvMjMwLw,,/
https://store.com/customer/account/login/referer/aHR0cHM6Ly9zdG9yZS5zbWFydGRlc2tzLmNvbS9jYXRhbG9nL2NhdGVnb3J5L3ZpZXcvaWQvMjMwLz9jb2xvcj01NjM1/
https://store.com/customer/account/login/referer/aHR0cHM6Ly9zdG9yZS5zbWFydGRlc2tzLmNvbS9jYXRhbG9nL2NhdGVnb3J5L3ZpZXcvaWQvMjMwLz9jb2xvcj01NjM2/
https://store.com/customer/account/login/referer/aHR0cHM6Ly9zdG9yZS5zbWFydGRlc2tzLmNvbS9jYXRhbG9nL2NhdGVnb3J5L3ZpZXcvaWQvMjMwLz9jb2xvcj01NjM3/
https://store.com/customer/account/login/referer/aHR0cHM6Ly9zdG9yZS5zbWFydGRlc2tzLmNvbS9jYXRhbG9nL2NhdGVnb3J5L3ZpZXcvaWQvMjMwLz9jb2xvcj01NjM4/
https://store.com/customer/account/login/referer/aHR0cHM6Ly9zdG9yZS5zbWFydGRlc2tzLmNvbS9jYXRhbG9nL2NhdGVnb3J5L3ZpZXcvaWQvMjMwLz9jb2xvcj01NjQw/
https://store.com/customer/account/login/referer/aHR0cHM6Ly9zdG9yZS5zbWFydGRlc2tzLmNvbS9jYXRhbG9nL2NhdGVnb3J5L3ZpZXcvaWQvMjMwLz9jb2xvcj01NjQx/
https://store.com/customer/account/login/referer/aHR0cHM6Ly9zdG9yZS5zbWFydGRlc2tzLmNvbS9jYXRhbG9nL2NhdGVnb3J5L3ZpZXcvaWQvMjMwLz9jb2xvcj01NjQy/
https://store.com/customer/account/login/referer/aHR0cHM6Ly9zdG9yZS5zbWFydGRlc2tzLmNvbS9jYXRhbG9nL2NhdGVnb3J5L3ZpZXcvaWQvMjMwLz9jb2xvcj01NjQz/

How can I properly add rel=canonical to /customer/account/login/referer/ ???

Comment: did you try my solution ?any issue ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add canonical tag for `../customer/account/login/` page.

Can be added using layout, like:

> app/design/frontend/{Package}/{my-theme}/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account_login.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
      <link rel="canonical" src="http://example.com/customer/account/login/" src_type="url"/>
</head>
</page>
```

**Note:** Replace URL with actual domain name.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks!

Comment: welcome @LouisB. :)